# Nagios calling 'mvn test' in a project returns a error, but without details

Tags: maven, maven-3, nagios

I have a command defined as:

```
define command {
command_name                    xyz_minimal_check
command_line                    mvn --global-settings=(dir)/settings.xml -f (proj)/pom.xml -Dtest=ThingTest#testThing test
}
```

and a service defined to call this command. When it runs, I see:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
```

But I do not see any details in any log. Where might these be? I am sure there are some things I need to set up or some environment variables I have to provide to the command that nagios is running, but I cannot tell what they are. I have looked in the usual logs and see nothing specific to this service.

This is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 system. The usual ping and http services in nagios are working fine.

Comment: What happens when you add -X on the end of the command for verbose output from maven?

Comment: The must be more output produces by Maven so where is stdout ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only place I can see the output of my command is in the web interface itself. Click on the service name and the output is in the description of the service there. It seems very strange that nothing goes into var/nagios.log or any other log file.....

And once I saw my output, I could see my errors. The issue was that I had to make it possible for the nagios user to run the "mvn test". My default, the permissions prevent this. The easiest way to do this is to create a directory owned by the nagios user, give it its own copy of the project, and give it its own .m2 directory. Then it will work.